# Regexp PHP Split number and string

Tags: php, regex, split, match

I would like to split a string contains some numbers and letters. Like this:

```
ABCd Abhe123
123ABCd Abhe
ABCd Abhe 123
123 ABCd Abhe
```

I tried this:

```
<?php preg_split('#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i', "ABCd Abhe 123"); ?>
```

But it doesn't work. Only one cell in array with "ABCd Abhe 123"
I would like for example, in cell 0: numbers and in cell1: string:

```
[0] => "123",
[1] => "ABCd Abhe"
```

Thank you for your help! ;)

Comment: So which output are you expecting for the string above?

Comment: If it's possible, an array like I wrote. (Thank you for editing my post :$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all` instead

```
preg_match_all("/(\d+)*\s?([A-Za-z]+)*/", "ABCd Abhe 123" $match);
```

For every match:

- `$match[i][0]` contains the matched segment
- `$match[i][1]` contains numbers
- `$match[i][2]` contains letters

(See [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/AriKvd8QVe) for regex test)

Then put them in an array

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($match); $i++)
{
    if($match[i][1] != "")
        $numbers[] = $match[1];

    if($match[i][2] != "")
        $letters[] = $match[2];
}
```

---

### EDIT1

I've updated [the regex](http://www.rubular.com/r/GpHEOhQbw4). It now looks for either numbers or letters, with or without a whitespace.

---

### EDIT2

The regex is correct, but the arrayhandling wasn't. Use `preg_match_all`, then `$match` is an array containing arrays, like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Abc
            [1] =>  aaa
            [2] => 25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Abc
            [1] => aaa
            [2] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't knew this web site! I just changed to: (\d+)|([\WA-Za-z]+) to use spaces. Thank you!

Comment: I come back ^^ It's strange, I have the letters but not the numbers... An idea ? But if I test here: http://www.rubular.com/r/X0RRECjww5, it works...

Comment: As you can see there, the numbers are all in index 1 of $match, while the letters are in index 2 of $match. Make sure you get the right index. Also, what do you use for input? A single, long string?

Comment: It's a normal string. I checked my input string and I have something like: Abc aaa25. Then, I check my arrays: count(numbers) and count(letters). One of them are 0 => numbers. I don't understand :/

Comment: Use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`, see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$numbers = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $input);
$letters = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $input);
```